# Google App Script Page break at cursor?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-docs-api

I have a button in my sidebar of which's purpose is to insert a page break where the cursor is. I tried scripting it to just insert a page break (not at the cursor but just in the body) and it works fine.

However, I can't seem to get it to work at the cursor:

```
function pageBreak() {
var cursor = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getOffset();
insertPageBreak(cursor);
}
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: You can use the `getCursor()` method directly after accessing the document body. [Here's the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document#getCursor()).

Comment: Alright, so after i use getCursor() instead of the getOffset(), how do I insert/append pagebreak at the cursor's position?

Answer (score 0):

You need to know the element type at the cursor position.  Not all element types allow a page break to be inserted.

Begin by getting the element at the cursor position, then work from there.

```
function insertPgBrk() {
  var theCursor = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getCursor();
  var theElement = theCursor.getElement();
  var elementTypeAtCursor = theElement.getType();
  Logger.log('elementTypeAtCursor: ' + elementTypeAtCursor);

  if (elementTypeAtCursor === DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH) {
    Logger.log('its the right type');
    theElement.insertPageBreak(0);
  };
};
```

You can't insert a page break in a TEXT element.  The element needs to be a PARAGRAPH or a LISTITEM.

Comment: Awesome, this makes much more sense. What would I do if I want some predefined text that's bolded and centered to be added (like "cookies are nice") on the new page following the pagebreak? Do I use `.editAsText()` or `FontFamily`?

Comment: You can use `body.appendParagrah('Cookies are nice')` and then style it with the ENUM values listed [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/attribute).

Comment: Don't know at the moment.  Might be better to ask a separate question.

Comment: Oh I just tried this out, it works fine only if I place my cursor at the end of my paragraph (which is fine for what I need to do). However, it causes my content to be pushed down and makes the new page my first page. Is there some way to force the new page to be pushed down?